# How to push data and detect changes in angular 2 + version?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

In previous angular version we had $scope.apply to detect changes , So i below code i have data from detailService that is printed now i am pushing data to object its throwing error object property is undefined , what is correct approach in new angular version to push data to array and bind it to the dom ?

app.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit,Pipe, PipeTransform, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { DetailService } from '../detail.service';
import { StreamService } from '../stream.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import {GtConfig} from '@angular-generic-table/core';
import { GenericTableComponent} from '@angular-generic-table/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';


export interface Element {
        ticketNum: number;
        ticketOpened: number;
        eventType: string;
        riskIndex: string;
        riskValue: number;
        severity: string;
        lastModifiedDate: number;
        assetID: string;
    }
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-detail',
      templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css'],

    })
export class DetailComponent{
  messageArray: any[];
    message1:Object = {};
   public secondConfigObject: GtConfig<any>;

    constructor(private detailService: DetailService) {
        this.secondConfigObject = {
            settings: this.getBaseSettings(),
            fields: this.getBaseFields(),
            data: []
        };
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        this.detailService.currentMessage1.subscribe(message1 => {
            console.log('eventINDetailComp',message1);
            this.secondConfigObject.data.push(message1);
        });
    }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <generic-table [gtClasses]="'table-hover'" #myCustomTable [gtSettings]="secondConfigObject.settings" [gtFields]="secondConfigObject.fields" [gtData]="secondConfigObject.data"></generic-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? If so, you can try removing that option. Otherwise, you will find a few ways to force change detection in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/1009922).

Comment: @ConnorsFan changes are automatically detected within angular 2+

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - Not always, especially with [ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/).

Comment: @ConnorsFan unless running something outside the angular scope, it always does, thats the benefits of using angular over angularjs or other frameworks

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - I invite you to take a look at the cases illustrated in [this document](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/).

Comment: i dont have that high level understanding i will really appreciate if you can provide code example as answer, document does not show any example

Comment: you dont need to follow the document he linked, its not a fix for your issue

Comment: its very simple i have data from service that i want to push it to `secondconfigObject.data` but this.detailSerive is invoking when application launched and it throws error undefined that is abvious because i dont have event at that time, its row clicked event that is passed to service from other component, not sure what is missing in the code

Comment: @ConnorsFan thats just other ways of writing it, but they arent needed

Comment: @hussain did you try implementing the `@Output()` i mentioned in the chat?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - Yeah, the question is about avoiding a run-time error, not about change detection. Maybe the title should be changed.

Comment: @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter<any>(); added this after component getting error `error TS1146: Declaration expected.`

Comment: `this.secondConfigObject.data.push(Object.assign({},message1))` this resolved the issue thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

You should move the code from the constructor to the start of the `ngOnInit()` function so the data gets set once the page has been created, not during.

As for data binding, variables on the screen/html will automatically update when they are changed in the code behind

Comment: it throws error at `message1.prop` is undefined if i move code inside `ngOnInit` not sure why this is invoking , this is row click event it should only invoke when we have data pass from detail service

Comment: where do you use message1.prop? i cant see it in your code?

Comment: i am just giving you example so in subscribe i have message1 that is the object coming from service now properties are undefined on that because this.detailService.currentMessage1 invoked on application launch it should not

Comment: if you put the subscribe in the ngOnInit, then it should be invoked when the application is launched

Comment: but i am passing the event when row is clicked in the table what will be correct approach in that case, basically passing data object from one table to another

Comment: you are passing the event straight away when the page loads, not when a row is clicked

Comment: i get event in detail serivce when row is clicked so now how to push event in `secondConfigObject`  once i get it from service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163500/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-hussain).